# Tidying up history in RStudio to document an analysis

Tags: r

I am doing some analysis in Rstudio and at the moment - as I am refreshing my knowledge of R after a few decades away from S - this involves writing lots of one-liner statements which operate on test datasets, and then inspecting/testing the output, then finally scaling it up when I've checked all the little bits work.

So my history is full of syntax errors and similar.   But I am making progress every time I work, and each time I work there are statements that worked, that I want to save, in order to document the bits of the session that are worth saving.   Is there any established way of extracting these from my history for re-use, in RStudio?    Should I just scroll through after each session and copy and paste them into a textfile with a word processor?  Or is there something more clever than that that I can do, staying within RStudio?

Comment: I use 'send to source' and then do whatever I want with it there. Another possibility is to select lines you want to delete and click the "Remove the selected history entries" button. Another possibility is to click the "Save history into a file" button. A better place to ask this question would probably have been on stackoverflow with the "rstudio" tag, or on rstudio's forums

Comment: Thanks, Glen.  My guess is that asking this on stackoverflow would have a attracted a lot of community policing action, as so many questions do, and I didn't feel like risking it.  RStudio's forum is an interesting option which I haven't explored yet.  Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the history panel in RStudio (top right panel), you can click "send to source" and it will copy the line you have selected over to whatever .R file you have open in the top left panel.

Comment: Thanks!  This sounds like exactly what I need.  I am not sure how to create or open an .R file other than the defaults, but will look this up.

Comment: File->New Script should get you a source file to dump code into.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to see your history, is to hit Ctrl-4 and that will bring up the history window.  You can copy this to source and then edit it, or where ever.  However, for what you are doing it is probably better to edit directly into a source window.

The setup I use is to have a script window open, and use ctrl-enter to run the current line.

To make this easier go into Tools>Options>Code Editing and ensure that "focus console after executing from source" is unchecked and your cursor will stay in the script after the line is executed.

[image]

You can now type your lines and edit them until they do what you want, then move on to the next when it works.  Once you get to the end you have built up your script already.  Also since your "history" is just their in front of you, it is much easier to skip back to older lines and rerun or modify them.  If you want to run a block of code, simply highlight the block and hit ctrl-enter.

Comment: Thanks for your tips!   I think what I am missing here is that I don't understand what a script window is, or how to get/create one.  I have checked the documentation over and over, but will ask this on the RStudio forum.  It's pretty basic but it's not clear to me from reading about it.

Comment: Try File>New>R Script.  Or just hit Ctrl+Shift+N

Comment: For the work you have just done, you need to hit Ctrl+4 to bring up the history window.  Then hit Ctrl+Shift+N to get a new script.  You can now go through the history window selecting each line you want, and either press the "To Source" button, or simply hit Shift+Enter.  This will gradually build up your script.